# Auto fill password with Expo Applications

Tags: react-native, expo

Problem is simple;

Projects that are developed by expo doesnt ask anyone "do you want to save your password" question. So everyone, everytime must type their email and password again and again.

How can I register my app, to be asked "do you want to save your password" question. android & ios.

Answer (score 1):

This does not straight away solve your problem, but offers some information to improve your application.

If you have users with email and password authentication I would assume you are using some backend or service for that.
You can have a function that listens if user is logged in and if he is, it will automatically detect it and continue accordingly.

For example I use Firebase and recommend it (I'm biased about this but I will use it as example).
In my root I have function that listens Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` function and by it returns information if user is logged in or not. This way my application right away is logged in or needs logging in.
I myself don't use automatic email/password filling but with these things I don't need that functionality at the moment.
Refrerence: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: I believe they are asking about password autofill on the login screen and not auth state in the application.